# What to call someone who understands things? (As if that is their talent)

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I know that Richard Feynman is called: “The Great Explainer”. What would be the “opposite”? The Great “one who understands well”.

Sentence:

> She is such a great _______, she understands things so well, and quickly, without anyone telling her how it works. She gets it by herself.

Answer (score 1):

***empath***

> (especially in science fiction stories) a person who has an unusually strong ability to feel other people's emotional or mental states:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/empath)

Possibly this post belongs on Literature.SE.

...but the topic goes back to Andre Norton, and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

"intuitive" seems to describe her. I don't think there's a noun form of this word, but the adjective can be used as a noun. So the phrase would be "The Great Intuitive".

Or you could make up the word "Intuiter". It's not in the dictionaries I checked, but it would be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Assimilator. Assimilate caries the sense of absorbing and hence understanding thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***the Great Perceiver***:

He who is *perceptive*, who *perceives* is

> capable of or exhibiting keen perception : OBSERVANT and
> characterized by sympathetic understanding or insight ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceptive#:%7E:text=%3A%20capable%20of%20or%20exhibiting%20keen,perceptiveness%20noun))

and

> very good at noticing and understanding things that many people do not notice ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perceptive))

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a person who is considered to be Clever and sensible. Even by their own admission!the word I would use is proclivity.ie. He or she has a proclivity to a deep understanding.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).